# Технологии для работы с базой данных

Tags: c#, mysql, ado

Подскажите пожалуйста,какие есть технологии или библиотеки для работы с базой данных, среда разработки visual studio 2013, проект windows forms, помимо ado.net?

Comment: Евгений, вопрос нельзя удалить, на него уже даны ответы. Если очень нужно, можно сделать его анонимным.

Answer (score 4):

Entity Framework и NHibernate.
Если не ошибаюсь то LINQ to SQL мертв и не развивается.

Если работа ведется через с базами Access, то можно воспользоваться Interop.

Dapper неплохая мини ORM. С помощью этой либы упрощается код. Например, работа с параметрами облегчается.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью Entity Framework можно работать с БД через DataGridView в Windows Forms, аналогично DataSet в ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)